# Why does my window not show up in python when using these 'while loops'?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

Please help with this piece of code when I run it, nothing shows up?
But before I ran it without the loops, it worked pretty fine.
In the 'Errors' part it only said  '====== RESTART: C:/Users/---/OneDrive/Desktop/Tkinter program test.py ======'

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint


def pressbutton_1_10():
    randomnumber.delete(0.0, END)
    randomnumber.insert(END, str(randint(1, 10)))


def pressbutton_1_100():
    randomnumber.delete(0.0, END)
    randomnumber.insert(END, str(randint(1, 100)))

def pressed_the_button_a():
    pressbutton_1_10()
    button1.forget()
    have_not_pressed_buttons == False

def pressed_the_button_b():
    pressbutton_1_100()
    button2.forget()
    have_not_pressed_buttons = False


again = True
while again == True:
    background = Tk()
    have_not_pressed_buttons = True
    randomnumber = Text(background, width=100, height=10)
    randomnumber.pack()
    while have_not_pressed_buttons == True:
        button1 = Button(background, text='Press for a random number between 1 and 10', command=pressed_the_button_a)
        button1.pack()
        button2 = Button(background, text='Press for a random number between 1 and 100', command=pressed_the_button_b)

        button2.pack()
    restart = Button(background, text='Press to get the buttons back', command = again == True)
    stop = Button(background, test = 'Press to end the program', command = again == False)
    restart.pack()
    stop.pack()
    background.bind_all('<Button-1>', pressed_the_button_a)
    background.bind_all('<Button-1>', pressed_the_button_b)
```

Comment: Why it has to run in a loop?

Comment: Tkinter does not work well with while loops, and usually you don't really need any since the `mainloop` already is a loop. With the current code you keep creating new Buttons without giving the user a chance to click one.